# Error decoding image in PHP: "Data is not in a recognized format"

Tags: php, gd, tiff

Getting the error "Data is not in a recognized format" when I try to decode an image from XML. Does this have to do with the fact that it's a Tiff image?

PHP:

```
$rep110 = xmlUrl;
$rep110 = urldecode($rep110);
$report110 = simplexml_load_file($rep110);
$docsData = $report110->Document->Content[0];
$docsDecoded = base64_decode((string)$docsData);
$im = imagecreatefromstring($docsDecoded); // *** this line throws the error ***
```

The XML:

```
<XML110...>
    <Document>
        <FileName>cdc4aa19-49fc-4d22-95b5-b4fc78.tif</FileName>
        <Content>
        SUkqAM4fAAD///+dhdC+96Cj...
        </Content>
    </Document>
    ...
</XML110>
```

Comment: From the manual: `These types will be automatically detected if your build of PHP supports them: JPEG, PNG, GIF, WBMP, and GD2.`. I don't see TIFF anywhere...

Comment: Try trimming the string before you try to decode it.

Comment: Do you have any of the various ImageMagick extensions installed, or maybe have the program itself installed?  You should be able to use it to convert the TIFF into something GD understands, if ImageMagick itself doesn't do what you need.